# Assign IP Address on DNS

Tags: ip

I am a new user in Linux,just started and was given this project to install a new DNS server. I have already installed the server using Ubuntu 14.04.04. 
Now I need to assign the IP address to the DNS Server, How do I do that? please advise and tips are needed.

Kind Regards
PDickson

Answer (score 1):

You configure the IP address of the machine on `/etc/network/interfaces`: for instance

```
  auto eth0
    iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.0.2.7
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.0.2.254
```

More info can be found on the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/interfaces.5.html).

Answer (score -3):

You could try this:

```
ifconfig eth0 up
ifconfig 192.0.2.1 up
```

and then this:

```
ifconfig "1" up
```

and it might work fine this way.